# como pegar JsonProperty.Name

Tags: c#, json

tenho a seguinte classe:

```
    public class Planilha
{
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Contrato { get; set; }
    public string Vencimento { get; set; }
    public string Acesso { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Razão Social")]
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Nome Fantasia")]
    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
    public string Parceiro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string UF { get; set; }
}
```

em um momento do codigo eu tenho um array de Planilhas, percorro esse array e para cada propriedade preciso pegar esse JsonProperty

```
foreach (PlanilhaPrecisao item in planihaPrecisao)
            {
                var x = "nome da propriedade /* ou JsonProperty";


            }
```

ou seja, quando chegar na propriedade RazaoSocial  eu preciso que x seja igual  "Razão Social", como faço isso ?

Comment: não está bem claro, no exemplo tem a classe "Planilha" e no foreach "PlanilhaPrecisao"

Answer (score 0):

Utilize [Reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) para acessar os atributos de uma propriedade.

```
PropertyInfo[] todasAsPropriedadesDePlanilha = typeof(Planilha).GetProperties();
```

Dessa forma voce tem acesso a todas as propriedades que existe em `Planilha`.
Entao voce pode facilmente percorrer essas propriedades e acessar os atributos que ela possui.

Como voce sabe que precisa de `JsonPropertyAttribute` basta usar o metodo `GetCustomAttribute` que esta dentro de `PropertyInfo`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo onde eu estou percorrendo todas as propriedades de `Planilha`.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Reflection;

foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Planilha).GetProperties())
{
    string nomePropriedadeOuValorAtributo = string.Empty;
    var atributo = property.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();
    if (atributo != null)
    {
        nomePropriedadeOuValorAtributo = atributo.PropertyName;
    }
    else
    {
        nomePropriedadeOuValorAtributo = property.Name;
    }
}
```

De acordo com a pergunta voce precisa de `JsonProperty` ou o nome da propriedade, eu adicionei uma simples condição caso nao exista o atributo.

Dentro de `PropertyInfo` tambem existe o metodo `GetProperty` onde ele recebe como parametro o nome da propriedade. Entao se voce quer acessar o atributo da sua propriedade `RazaoSocial` aplicando em seu codigo, ficaria mais ou menos dessa forma.

```
foreach (PlanilhaPrecisao item in planihaPrecisao)
{
     string nomePropriedadeOuValorAtributo = nameof(item.RazaoSocial);
     PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Planilha).GetProperty(nomePropriedadeOuValorAtributo);
     var atributo = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();
     if (atributo != null)
     {
          nomePropriedadeOuValorAtributo = atributo.PropertyName;
     }
}
```